# Получение полигонов, соответствующих городам России

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

**Предельно кратко:** Возможно ли с помощью АПИ получить полигоны, соответствующие территориям городов России?

**Чуть подробнее:** Хотелось бы использовать возможности описанные в примере:
https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/route_inside_polygon

и по Москве получилось адаптировать этот пример под бизнес-задачу, но проблема в том, что требуется реализовать такую функциональность под использование в разных городах России. Понимаю, что можно создавать json-файлы с координатами нужных полигонов под каждый из городов, подобно тому как это сделано для Москвы в примере указанном выше, но хотелось бы автоматизировать этот процесс.

**Максимально подробно:** на всякий случай опишу целиком задачу, возможно вы подскажите совершенно другой способ её решения с помощью АПИ, который я не увидел. Требования такие:

1. Возможность построить маршрут от точки А (адрес производства) до точки B (адрес клиента)
2. Рассчитать расстояние от границы города до точки B по проложенному маршруту

С первой задачей проблем не возникло, со второй задачей - получилось сделать решение на базе примера, который я привел выше, для Москвы. Также получилось сделать вручную файл json с координатами полигона для еще одного произвольного города.

Что не получилось сделать:

1. Не получилось найти в АПИ способа получить полигон (в виде координат точек) программным способом (через наименование города, или какой то другой идентификатор).
2. Не получилось найти какой либо другой способ в АПИ определить расстояние той части построенного маршрута (из точки А в точку В), которая лежит вне города (в котором расположена точка А)

Comment: в API Карт Яндекса полигоны городов недоступны

Comment: для вашей задачи понадобится как и в примере найти полигоны городов из стороннего источника, а потом уже использовать их в API

Comment: спасибо, да видел аналогичные рекомендации, пробовал искать такие источники, но найти источники, где были бы все (хотя бы крупные) города,  не получилось

Comment: попробуйте из OSM выгрузить, только они требуют их копирайт показать на итоговой веб-странице